# How to reverse ESC and CAPS_LOCK on TTY

Tags: console, keyboard-layout

I'm looking for a way to swap <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on Linux virtual console.

In X11, I can do this with `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`, but I don't know an equivalent in text mode. So, what can I do?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux should help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First You Need To install "console-data"

```
sudo apt-get install console-data
```

Now use "sudo showkey" to find the keycode of your ESC and CapsLock key

```
sudo showkey
```

My keycode for ESC was "1" and for Caps Lock was "58"

Now you need to create a .keystrings file in your home directory

```
vim ~/.keystrings
```

In that file you'll swap the keycode's for Caps Lock and ESC ex. since the Caps Lock Key was equal to 58 before I'll make it equal to 1

```
keycode 1 = Caps_Lock
keycode 58 = Escape
```

Now Save and close your .keystrings file and run the following command in your TTY

```
sudo loadkeys .keystrings
```

The Caps Lock and Escape keys should now be swapped

Comment: Just a little question: how can I load `loadkeys` at each boot?

Answer (score 1):

For Debian based systems, the procedure is quite straightforward. Look for the line `XKBOPTIONS=` in `/etc/default/keyboard` and change it to

```
XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"
```

Root access will be required, of course. And don't worry, despite the "X" the console should have <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> reversed upon reboot.

Read `man keyboard` and [Changing the keyboard layout/mapping on both the console (tty) and X in an X/console agnostic way?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479673) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

## Step by step solution

### X11

The following command sets the **X11** keyboard correctly (de is my keyboard layout):

`localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap de "" "" caps:swapescape`

### tty

The **tty** keyboard can be configured as follows:

1. Copy the correct keyboard layout file to a custom directory:

`cp /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwertz/de-latin1.map.gz /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps`

(You will have to change that command depending on what keyboard layout you are using)

2. Change every occurency of `Escape` to `Caps_Lock` and every occurency of `Caps_Lock` to `Escape` in the copied file and rename it to something like `de-latin1-custom.map.gz`
3. Edit the `/etc/vconsole.conf` file to look like this:

`KEYMAP="/usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/de-latin1-custom.map.gz"`

After rebooting the system the keyboard should be configured correctly for **X11** and for **tty**.