# Changing the keyboard layout/mapping on both the console (tty) and X in an X/console agnostic way?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've been able to change the keyboard layout/mapping when the [X Window System](https://www.x.org/wiki/) is running using `~/.Xmodmap` (and I suppose you could also do it through the [X protocol](https://www.x.org/docs/XProtocol/proto.pdf) directly, eg. using [libxcb](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/) as a wrapper around X protocol calls).

I've been able to do the same (somewhat) on the console/tty (ie. when X is not running) using `loadkeys`.

> Is there a way to customize the keyboard layout similarly, but from a *single source*, in such a way that it affects both X and the console, ie. in a way that is "X-and-console agnostic"?

(The only way I can think of is by writing a "keyboard driver" that talks to the kernel's input interface, `evdev`, and sends the input you want (through `uinput`?), or something, but I don't know if this even makes sense, or if there's an easier way.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keyboard hard remap keys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156985/keyboard-hard-remap-keys)

Comment: Which distro? On debian there is a `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, on Red Hat: `localectl set-keymap` and similar. Is this what you need? [Related1](https://superuser.com/a/404507/897702) and [Related2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration)

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't involve adjusting the console keymapping -- the OP specified that they "did not try loadkeys, as [the affected app] is running on X".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, and this is indeed how Debian's console-setup package does it.

- Keyboard layouts are specified in XKB terms (model, layout, variant, and options) by the administrator in a file named `keyboard`, usually `/etc/default/keyboard`.  This is the single source.  It can be edited with a text editor.
- The `setxkbmap` program is given these same XKB settings and configures an X11 server accordingly.

  - The keyboard-configuration package's post-installation maintainer script runs `setxkbmap` directly, with the `/etc/default/keyboard` settings, if it finds itself with an X11 display.  Thus `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` run from an X11 GUI terminal emulator will affect the X11 keyboard layout.
- The `setupcon` script takes these XKB settings, passes them through the `ckbcomp` utility to generate a keyboard map, and loads that keyboard map into the kernel virtual terminals with `loadkeys`/`kbdcontrol`.

  - This script is run at system bootstrap by a service.
  - It can also be run manually elsewhen.

Other systemd operating systems work differently but also have a single source.

- The XKB layout, variant, and options are stored in in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`.  This is the single source.

  - This file is directly read by the X11 server at startup and sets the X11 keyboard map directly.
  - This file is parsed by `systemd-localed` at startup.  The file cannot be usefully edited with a text editor whilst `systemd-localed` is running, because the service will blithely overwrite it with its own in-memory information.
  - To change the XKB information, one runs `localectl`, which talks to another server which in turn talks to `systemd-localed`.
- `systemd-localed` converts the XKB settings to a virtual terminal keyboard map name using the mappings in `/usr/share/systemd/kbd-model-map`, which it then writes out to `/etc/vconsole.conf`.  Unlike the Debian system, it does not generate maps on the fly from the XKB information, but selects only pre-supplied static maps listed in the map file.
- `systemd-vconsole-setup` runs at bootstrap, reads `/etc/vconsole.conf`, and loads the keyboard map into the kernel virtual terminals by running `loadkeys`.

## Further reading

- [`keyboard`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/keyboard-configuration/keyboard.5.en.html).  *console-setup User's Manual*. Debian.
- [`ckbcomp`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/console-setup/ckbcomp.1.en.html).  *console-setup User's Manual*. Debian.
- Andrew T. Young (2011). *[Keyboard Configuration](https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/debian/keyboard.html)*.
- [Where is Xkb getting its configuration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66624/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326804/5132