# How to switch keyboard language in vtty?

Tags: keyboard, tty, keyboard-layout

How to switch keyboard language in vtty? No X involved, I just booted as root bypassing everything, and need to deal with files in language other than English. I think it's Linux Mint but not sure, helping a friend to fix the PC.

Comment: Have a look at `loadkeys`, `dumpkeys`, `keymaps` (man pages). If you need to "deal with files", you might need to be able to display UTF-8 charsets, and not set "keyboard language" (but your question is unclear on that point).

Comment: You need to find out what operating system it is.  It is important.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479720/5132