# Alt Gr not working under antiX terminal

Tags: debian, terminal, keyboard, dpkg, antix

I have an antix installation which has this problem, when I'm trying to use Alt Gr + 2, the terminal just outputs the number 2, leaving me without the @ special character. This happens the same to the other special characters requiring Alt Gr or Ctl Alt.
When I do a `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and restart the computer, I'm able to get the special characters, but randomly the problem gets back. With setupcon I can get it back but that's a little bit weird because when I power off or reboot the machine several times again the problem comes back.
Another strange thing is that when I open the X server on the machine the keyboard is able to output the special characters without any configuration.
So this looks like a terminal problem, could somebody give me some help please ?
Antix is based on Debian so I can try to use some solution related to debian.
Regards.

Comment: I am not understanding your issue. (1) Shouldn't `@` be produced by `Shift-2` (not AltGr-2 nor Ctl-Alt-2) ?  (2) Do you have the same problem in some other terminal, like UXterm, or Gnome-terminal, or some other you can try ?

Comment: This question will benefit from the output of `systemctl status console-setup.service keyboard-setup.service` in the question, as well as the contents of `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: @Issac that's because Im using a Spanish keyboard.

Comment: @JdeP allright thanks I will try to do that.

Comment: @Adrián Bueno, haberlo dicho antes, No?. Por cierto, me llamo Isaac, no eso que pusiste. Gracias. Which keyboard have you installed (cat /etc/default/keyboard)?

Comment: @Isaac perdona amigo es que estaba con el móvil. Me pone lo siguiente : XKBMODEL="pc105" XKBLAYOUT="es" XKBVARIANT="winkeys" XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp" BACKSPACE="guess"

Comment: @JdeBP I dont have the systemctl command, should I install it?

Comment: Adrián No, AntiX is made to avoid the use of systemd. Do not install it!!! It will (most probably) break your system. @JdeBP Is simply wrong.

Comment: @Adrián Are you talking about a terminal that you start on X, like in this image https://www.bitblokes.de/wp-content/gallery/antix-m12/antix-x12-test-2-10-terminal.jpg

Comment: @Adrián Or are you talking about the consoles that are accessed with CTRL-ALT-F1 to CTRL-ALT-F6 ? Because the xkb configuration has nothing to do with such consoles.

Comment: You need to tell answerers what parts of the Debian mechanism for this are present and whether they are working.  That's the current Debian way to obtain the requisite information.  Substitute your Debian derivative's way of providing the status of these services as appropriate.  Not having these services is a datum, too.  Ironically, Isaac clearly hasn't remembered how Debian does this.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479720/5132

Comment: @Adrián Lograste resolver?

Comment: @JdeBP (1)Are you claiming that there are console keyboard services in AntiX (2) Are you claiming that XKB is required to use loadkeys ?.