# Scrolling TTY without dedicated PgUp and PgDown

Tags: debian, tty, keyboard-layout, console, scrolling

**Stop reading if `uname -r` returns a Linux version greater than 5.9**, since scrollback has been simply removed ([1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=973c096f6a85e5b5f2a295126ba6928d9a6afd45), [2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=50145474f6ef4a9c19205b173da6264a644c7489)).

---

My keyboard does not have separate PgUp and PgDown keys.
They are in the numpad, sharing their position with KP_9 and KP_3.

[image: Keypad picture]

Scrolling terminals with `Shift+Pg{Up,Down}` was not possible either with
Numlock on or off.

Since I don't care for the keypad numbers but do care a lot for scrolling,
I have successfully remapped them in X11 to "Prior" and "Next" regardless
of Numlock state, and now `Shift+{PgUp,Down}` both work in Xterm.

However, I can't achieve the same in the TTY. With other keyboards that had exclusive Page keys, I could use `Shift+PgUp` to scroll back after `cat`ing a large file, for example.

#### Original keycodes

As of `showkeys`:

```
KP_3/KP_PgUp   = 73
KP_9/KP_PgDown = 81
Slash          = 89
Right Shift    = 54
```

As of `dumpkeys`:

```
PgUp   = 104
PgDown = 109
```

Slash and Right Shift were also listed because I will also swap them just
for testing.

#### Attempts

- Modified `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc` to exactly this:

  ```
  keycode 73 = Prior
    shift keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift shiftl  keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift shiftr  keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift shiftl  shiftr  keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift ctrll keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift shiftl  ctrll keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift shiftr  ctrll keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward
    shift shiftl  shiftr  ctrll keycode 73 = Scroll_Backward 
  keycode 81 = Next
    shift keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift shiftl  keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift shiftr  keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift shiftl  shiftr  keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift ctrll keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift shiftl  ctrll keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift shiftr  ctrll keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward
    shift shiftl  shiftr  ctrll keycode 81 = Scroll_Forward  
  keycode  89 = Shift
  keycode  54 = slash
    shift keycode  54 = question
    altgr keycode  54 = degree
    shift altgr keycode  54 = questiondown
  ```
- Followed the instructions of [How to change console keymap in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux).

  ```
  dumpkeys > pageupdown
  ```

  Then swapped

  ```
  keycode 73  keycode 104
  keycode 81  keycode 109
  keycode 54  keycode 89
  ```

  in that file and issued `loadkeys -s pageupdown`.

#### Results

In both experiments,

- Although the two keypad keys don't print numbers anymore and `PgUp` still
  works (it scrolls in `less`) as desired, `Shift+PgUp` does not scroll the TTY.
- Right Shift and Slash have been correctly swapped.

#### Additional notes

- Toggling Numlock does not help in any of the configurations. The Fn key
  also does not have any effect in those keys.
- I have also tried mapping more
  ordinary keys, namely `l` and `p`, to the Page actions, without success.
- If it helps in any way, this is the XKB map that works in the X session:

  ```
  partial keypad_keys
  xkb_symbols "noKPNumbers" {
      key  <KP9> {  [  Prior,   Prior   ]   };
      key  <KP3> {  [  Next,    Next    ]   };
  };
  ```

How can I map the keypad PgUp and PgDown keys in such a way that `Shift+Pg{Up,Down}`
scroll the TTY buffer? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You _should_ be able to achieve this by editing `/etc/default/keyboard` on Debian-based systems. However, I couldn't get it to work outside of X either...

Comment: @hedgie Thank you for your feedback. I had already tried something along that route, but the results were not any better. Differently from it, I believe the two presented methods are much more direct and that it is less probable to miss something in them than in the default/keyboard approach.

Comment: I had added and removed an answer for doing it in X, as I realized you have done this already for X. Could [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479673/changing-the-keyboard-layout-mapping-on-both-the-console-tty-and-x-in-an-x-con) help you into what you are trying?

Comment: @thanasisp Thanks for your help and the link, I had already gone through that post too. But see how, at the end, `loadkeys` is responsible for loading the keymap, confirming that my approach is technically correct.

Comment: Not a solution, a workaround: Launch `tmux` or `screen` after logging in and use their respective scrollback. The advantage being that you don't have to care where and how the shell is launched (tty, serial, xterm, something else), the scrolling works the same every time. You also get copy/paste everywhere which is nice.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it doesn't work is that you are trying to add form control to a formless output. There is no Buffer to scroll.

That may not seem to make sense, so let me explain. TTY is a historical artifact from when Console output was to an actual TTY or TeleTYpe device. It was a serial terminal printer, search up a LA120 from DEC for an example. You can actually still do this hooking a line printer into /dev/tty. Some server hardware also will allow you to redirect this output at the  BIOS level to a serial device. It comes in darn handy if you know how to use it in the absolute worst case hardware troubleshooting scenarios.

The TTY printer would print every line just as it happened and then the paper piled up on the floor of the Operations room. What is on the screen is just what was printed within the screen buffer. there is no other retained information to scroll though.

The Console TTY is meant as a last ditch effort to retain some sort of log even when everything else shits the bed. Its where the disk full message or the seg fault that halts the system shows up to give the actual operator some clue why the system is using electricity but not being otherwise useful.

Comment: Thank you for all the historic background, but I have always scrolled with `Shift+Pg{Up,Down}`, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/15255070. Are we talking about the same thing, the TTYs 1 to 7 that one gets with `CTRL-ALT-F{1..7}`, which have a framebuffer? Also, if there were no buffer to scroll, why would the keymap contain (by default!) actions such as `Scroll_Backward`?

Comment: I am not talking about the launchable /dev/tty# that you can use, those Sub-shells similar to running `screen` are buffered. I am talking about the console output that appears on the screen at the login prompt. Console output is TTY based. The keymap is for when you are operating within a shell or shell application like login. The console output is not within a shell or any buffered environment thus you cannot scroll it. I find the Function Key launched shells less useful than `screen` because you can't copy and paste data between them. `screen` is something I install on every system I admin.

Comment: I am talking about the console output when I have already logged in and already have the login shell. I want to scroll back when I `cat` a large file, for example. That one is scrollable. I'm sorry if I didn't convey it precisely enough in the question, I guess, but thank you for your answer anyway, it is very informative.

Comment: @someone Why the downvote? Care to explain so we all could know your point of view ?