# How to swap Escape and Caps Lock for tty and X11

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, tty, keyboard-layout

I have done quite a lot of research on how to swap the Escape and Caps Lock keys.
I achieved it while using **X11** via my `.xinitrc` file and the following line of code:

`setxkbdmap -option caps:swapescape`

However, when I start a **tty**, it doesn't work.
How can I get this to work while using a **tty**?
Is it possible to use some kind of global option, like a custom keyboard layout that does not depend on **X11**?

I'm using Arch Linux, if that helps.

Comment: [How to change console keymap in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux).

Comment: The output of `dumpkeys | head -1` shows `keymaps 0-2,4-6,8-10,12` for my current keyboard layout (de-latin1), should I put that output or the suggested output of `keymaps 0-127` in the file?

Comment: Also, why is it called CtrlL_Lock and not Caps_Lock?

Comment: I'm not using Arch Linux, but maybe try adding `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` to `/etc/default/keyboard` (it works in Debian with both vts and xorg). Otherwise, you can do it by hand with `dumpkeys | sed 's/keycode  *58 =.*/keycode 58 = Control/' | loadkeys` (you may have to adjust the sed expression, check with `showkey` and `dumpkeys | less` before).

Comment: Sorry, that was about `nocaps` ;-) but it may still give you the idea how to tackle `swapescape` too.

Comment: The file doesn't exist, should I create it?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then it means that Arch Linux isn't using it. Try the manual method instead.

Comment: Where should I put that code?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479673/5132 .

Comment: Though not very clean, you can put in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/`, and make it conditional on the type of terminal: `[ "$TERM" = linux ] && dumpkeys | ... | loadkeys`.

Comment: @JdeBP The thing is, the only answer was about how to do it in debian and I'm using Arch, where the /etc/default/keyboard file doesn't exist...

Comment: Okay, changed the question, because I did it for **X11**. Now I just need to do it for **tty**. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and actually might have some value for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Step by step solution

### X11

The following command sets the **X11** keyboard correctly (de is my keyboard layout):

`localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap de "" "" caps:swapescape`

### tty

The **tty** keyboard can be configured as follows:

1. Copy the correct keyboard layout file to a custom directory:

`cp /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwertz/de-latin1.map.gz /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps`

(You will have to change that command depending on what keyboard layout you are using)

2. Change every occurency of `Escape` to `Caps_Lock` and every occurency of `Caps_Lock` to `Escape` in the copied file and rename it to something like `de-latin1-custom.map.gz`
3. Edit the `/etc/vconsole.conf` file to look like this:

`KEYMAP="/usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/de-latin1-custom.map.gz"`

After rebooting the system the keyboard should be configured correctly for **X11** and for **tty**.