# In Debian, how to change keyboard mapping in a single USER-SPECIFIC file to be used by X (via setxkbmap) and (kernel) virtual consoles (TTYs)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

This is NOT a duplicate of [Changing the keyboard layout/mapping on both the console (tty) and X in an X/console agnostic way?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479673/65627), where a **system-wide** `/etc/default/keyboard` is discussed.

I'm looking to use a **user-specific** file, `~/.keyboard`, with `xkb` settings that is used by both X (e.g., + LXDE), as well as by the (kernel) virtual consoles (VTs/TTYs).

As may be seen from `cat $(which setupcon)`, virtual consoles can pick up a user-specific `~/.keyboard` file (or a `VARIANT` thereof) if user's environment is preserved when `setupcon` is run:

```
sudo -E setupcon
```

where `setupcon` will (more or less) convert the xkb-based `~/.keyboard` settings (`XKBMODEL`, `XKBLAYOUT`, `XKBOPTIONS`, etc.) into console keymap type (via `ckbcomp`) and `loadkeys` the result into consoles. If user's environment is NOT preserved,

```
sudo setupcon
```

then `/etc/default/keyboard` is picked up.

**However, as far I can see, in X `setxkbmap` only picks up the system-wide `/etc/default/keyboard` file. The user-specific `~/.keyboard` is not picked up by `setxkbmap`**. But that is what I need. In other words, I'm trying to feed `~/.keyboard` to `setxkbmap`. I would like to be able to have this done both at X login (e.g., with a line in `~/.xsessionrc`), as well as to be able to make changes to `~/.keyboard` while in X and have them applied through `setxkbmap` (without `sudo`), much like `setxkbmap -option` provides.

Note that I'm NOT trying to manually create a user-specific xkb directory hierarchy and use that with `xkbcomp -I`. However, if there is an automated way of doing that with `~/.keyboard` as the input, that could be an acceptable workaround.

As of now, the only way I see is a hack: manually parse `~/.keyboard`, extracting `XKBOPTIONS` and then write an equivalent `setxkbmap -option` for each. I cannot believe for this hack to be the only way, although seeing https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/02/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-1.html makes me question that belief.

As of now I'm using Debian with X (+ LXDE). I don't think it makes a difference for Wayland, but if it does, please explain.

Comment: I think the hack you mention is indeed the only way. However, you don't need to do it manually, you can automate the process with Sed (although it is still a shame that there is no way to directly use the file). If you are interested, I can write an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Quasimodo. Yes, using sed, awk, python, etc., is what I meant by "manually parse `~/.keyboard` ...", as opposed to have it automatically read by `setxkbmap`. I can do that myself, but it is hard to believe this feature is not there in `setxkbmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is useful to someone else, here is the hack I mentioned
above that I ended up using for now.

`~/bin/setxkbmap.sh` parses `~/.keyboard`, extracting the xkb
settings, and runs equivalent setxkbmap command(s) in X.
`~/bin/setxkbmap.sh` may be called manually, or
automatically at X startup through a line in, e.g.,
`~/.xsessionrc`.

`~/bin/setxkbmap.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Parse ~/.keyboard, extracting the xkb settings, and run equivalent
# setxkbmap command(s) in X.

source ~/.keyboard
setxkbmap_cmd=(setxkbmap -model "${XKBMODEL}")
setxkbmap_cmd+=(-layout "${XKBLAYOUT}")

# Clear previously-set options first; otherwise, these will be
# appended to whatever is already there.
setxkbmap_cmd+=(-option)

# -r      : do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
# -a array: assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
#           variable ARRAY, starting at zero
IFS=',' read -r -a xkbopts <<< "${XKBOPTIONS}"
for opt in "${xkbopts[@]}"; do
    setxkbmap_cmd+=(-option "${opt}")
done

"${setxkbmap_cmd[@]}"
```

`~/.keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"

# ctrl: specifies options coming from /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl
# file.
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:menu_rctrl,ctrl:nocaps,ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

`~/.xsessionrc`:

```
# ~/.xsessionrc is sourced by Xsession (a sh script), everytime an X
# session is started. See 'man xsession' for details.

# Explicitly use bash, as ~/.xsessionrc is called by sh (dash in
# Debian 9 GNU/Linux).
bash ~/bin/setxkbmap.sh
```